# GExiv2.py (Python) hosted in Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, installation, package, exif

Typically I am a python user in the linux OS, but in this case I need to add a package to my Windows 7 OS. How do i install GExiv2.py on my Windows machine? For linux the the path is simple "$ sudo apt-get install libexiv2-dev"

Here is the limited information I have on the package:
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gexiv2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is a Windows build for this library at this time. There is an open bug on that [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=712441).

While it is deprecated, you can still use **pyexiv2**, which has a Windows installer [here](http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/download.html).